# Avoid duplicates to of new classes with the same code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a class which create an issue in Jira board. I want to use it in 5 different scenarios but the only things that will be different are required fields such as `summary`, `description`, and `issuetype`. How to handle such a scenario to avoid creating few classes with 90% the same content?

This is a main content of the class:

```
module Jira
  class TicketCreator
    def call
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(required_fields)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
    end

    def required_fields
       #data from below examples
    end
  end
end
```

Here are scenarios for required fields which I want to use depends on webhook information:

```
def required_fields
  {
    'fields' => {
      'summary' => 'Create new repo <github_repo> for <Github user>',
      'description' => 'This is an automatic confirmation of creating new PRIVATE repo
                      - <github_repo> for <Github user>',
      'project' => { 'key' => 'TEST' },
      'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12580' },
      'customfield_15100' => 'None'
    }
  }
end

def required_fields
  {
    'fields' => {
      'summary' => 'Add <Github user> collaborator to <github_repo>',
      'description' => 'This is an automatic ticket confirmation of user added',
      'project' => { 'key' => 'TEST' },
      'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12580' }, # nonautoresolved
      'customfield_15100' => 'None'
    }
  }
end

def required_fields
  {
    'fields' => {
      'summary' => 'Recheck <Github user> deleted <github_repo>',
      'description' => 'This is an automatic ticket confirmation of delete repo <github_repo>',
      'project' => { 'key' => 'TEST' }, # change to project_key
      'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12579' }, # autoresolved
      'customfield_15100' => 'None'
    }
  }
end
```

How to avoid creation new classes where the only difference will be this `required_fields` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use keyword arguments together with [Hash#reverse_merge](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-reverse_merge) to merge the default options with passed options:

```
module Jira
   class TicketCreator
     # Do setup at initializion instead
     def initialize
       # FIXME - style violation - this should be client.issue.build 
       @issue = client.Issue.build 
     end

     def call(**options)
       @issue.save(required_fields(options))
     end

     # Takes care of initializion so that you can call 
     # Jira::TicketCreator.call - you can DRY this though inheritance or mixins
     def self.call(**options)
       new.call(options)
     end

     private

     def client 
       @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
     end

     def required_fields(**options)
       {
         'fields' => {
           'summary' => 'Recheck <Github user> deleted <github_repo>',
           'description' => 'This is an automatic ticket confirmation of delete repo <github_repo>',
           'project' => { 'key' => 'SUP' }, # change to project_key
           'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12579' }, # autoresolved
           'customfield_15100' => 'None'
         }.reverse_merge(options.deep_stringify_keys)
       }
     end
   end
 end
```

---

```
 ticket = Jira::TicketCreator.call(
    project: { key: 'TEST' },
    issuetype: { id: '12580' }
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you send the required_fields to your class?

```
# TicketCreator.new(required_fields).call
module Jira
  class TicketCreator
    def initialize(required_fields)
      @required_fields = required_fields
    end

    def call
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(@required_fields)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
    end
  end
end
```

If you want a command for each one, you could use inheritance:

```
module Jira
  class Base
    def call
      issue = client.Issue.build
      issue.save(required_fields)
    end

    private

    def client
      @client ||= Jira::JiraConnection.new.call
    end

    def required_fields; end
  end
end

module Jira
  class CreateRepo < Base
    def required_fields
      {
        'fields' => {
          'summary' => 'Create new repo <github_repo> for <Github user>',
          'description' => 'This is an automatic confirmation of creating new PRIVATE repo
                      - <github_repo> for <Github user>',
          'project' => { 'key' => 'TEST' },
          'issuetype' => { 'id' => '12580' },
          'customfield_15100' => 'None'
        }
      }
    end
  end
end

module Jira
  class AddCollaborator < Base
    def required_fields
     {
      # data
     }
    end
  end
end
```